# Does the existence of independent standard Gaussian variables indexed on an interval guarantee almost sure measurable sample paths?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

We have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a collection of independent and identically distributed standard Gaussian variables $\left\{X_t : 0 \leq t \leq 1 \right\}$ on it. Is it true that $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is Borel-measurable function on $[0,1]$ with probability $1$ ?

It is easy to show that $(t, \omega) \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ can't be jointly measurable as in that case we can apply Fubini's Theorem and independence to conclude that
$$ \mathbb{E}\left( \int_{0}^t X_s \, ds \right)^2 = \int_{0}^t \int_{0}^t \mathbb{E}(X_uX_v) \; du \, dv =0,$$
implying that $\int_{0}^t X_s \, ds =0$, almost surely for all $t \in [0,1]$. Lebesgue differentiation theorem then gives us a contradiction.

But I don't know how to approach the original problem. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is non-Borel set in $[0,1]$ and $(Y_t)$ is i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ then $X_t=Y_t$ for $t \in E$ and $X_t=-Y_t$ for $t \notin E$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to tweak the construction a little bit as $X_t=Y_tI_{(Y_t \neq 0)} + I_{(Y_t =0)}$ for $t \in E$ and $X_t=-Y_t$ for $t \notin E$ to make it work, but that's a minor change. I was wondering whether we can say that the sample paths are not measurable with probability $1$. Is that true. Construction is a little bit difficult since the existence of such independent collection requires that $L^2(\Omega)$ is not separable.

Comment: @SouvikRay The existence of i.i.d. Gaussian random variables $(X_t)$ implies that $L^{2}(\Omega)$ is non-separable, right?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to construct an example where the sample paths are measurable with some positive probability. But the construction, if possible, might be difficult as we need to consider non-separable $L^2(\Omega)$.